# How to retrieve the current value of the description field in Dynamics 365 Activity Task record?

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365

I have a Dynamics 365 Activity Task record that contains a description with the value "Test Description Value".  I want to retrieve this value in a plug-in.

My main code is outlined below.

```csh
public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService((typeof(IPluginExecutionContext)));
    IOrganizationServiceFactory factory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
    IOrganizationService service = factory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);
    ITracingService tracingService = (ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));

    if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") && context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
    {
        Entity task = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];
        if (task.LogicalName == "task")
        {
            ColumnSet cs = new ColumnSet(new string[] { "description", "ownerid" });
            service.Retrieve("task", task.Id, cs);
            foreach (KeyValuePair<String, Object> attribute in task.Attributes)
            {
                tracingService.Trace(attribute.Key + ": " + attribute.Value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Iterating the foreach loop reveals that the `task.Attributes` does not contain a key for description, nor can I get the current value of the description using `task["description"]`.  Both return a System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException.

Is it possible to get the **current** value of the description field of an  Activity Task record in a plug-in?  How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going for explicit service call to retrieve extra task entity attributes, but missing a simple one.

```
Entity wholeTask = service.Retrieve("task", task.Id, cs);
```

And in iteration loop, use this retrieved entity instead of target entity.

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<String, Object> attribute in wholeTask.Attributes)
```

You can use preimage also if you want, which will avoid one more SDK call.

Comment: To include all attributes of the entity I had to change the ColumnSet line to 
    ColumnSet cs = new ColumnSet(true);  
but after that it works perfectly.  Thanks Arun.